# Property in propertyregex's regexp

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

I would like to use a property instead of a hardcoded text in the "regexp" attributes of the "propertyregex" Ant contrib task.

How can I do it so that the property is substituted first rather than its text used as the regex itself?

Example:

```
var name="regexp" value="${placeholder.start}|${placeholder.end}" />
<propertyregex property="a" input="${a.raw}" regexp="${regexp}" replace="" global="true" override="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<property>` to pass the regular expression to the `regexp` attribute:

```
<property name="a.raw" value="~_one_~ two ~_three_~" />
<property name="placeholder.start" value="~_" />
<property name="placeholder.end" value="_~" />
<property name="regexp" value="${placeholder.start}|${placeholder.end}" />
<propertyregex
    input="${a.raw}"
    regexp="${regexp}"
    replace=""
    global="true"
    property="a" />
<echo>${a}</echo>
```

### Output

```
[echo] one two three
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. Actually I found out the my problem was caused in loading and escaping the &lt; &gt; from a .properties file